# Control when the PHP include gets activated when placed on another page?

Tags: php

Is there i way i can control when a file gets included in another page?

When i click the link on 'index.html' called `<a href="/home.php">Home</a>`, the content of 'home.php' gets inserted in index.html- in the div #content".

But if the page 'home.php' contains `include 'index.html'`, 'index.html' will be shown 2 times when clicking the link `<a href="/home.php">Home</a>`.

Is there a way to stop the action `include 'index.html'` when clicking the link, but allowing the inclusion in all other situations?

I know the question is a bit confusing - dont be afraid to ask if you dont understand what im after. Heres some code:

**index.html**

```
// PART OF THE JQUERY/AJAX THAT LOADS CONTENT FROM home.php INTO index.html
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {    
    var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).text();

    History.pushState({urlPath: urlPath}, title, urlPath);
    $("#content").load(urlPath);    
    return false; 
});

<li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>

<div id="content">
'load home.php in here..'
</div>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php 
    include 'index.html';
?>

<div>   
    <h1>This is home.php that will be inserted into #content on index.html</h1>
    <p style="padding: 20px; background: green; color: yellow;">HOME HOME HOME.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is very confusing. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So it seems there is some AJAX content loading function here. Why would you just not remove the index.html include on home.php?  With this AJAX approach, you need all your target scripts from which content is loaded to just produce HTML fragments from inclusion in the main page.

Comment: Added AJAX and jQuery tags, since that is really what this is about.  You may want to edit question to be more clear on this point.

Comment: The reason the PHP include bit is needed on pages which are used in the AJAX-process is for bookmarking and page refresh - when i copy and paste the URL of 'home.php' it will not show the stuff (menu etc) from 'index.html' unless its included by PHP (could be JQuery as well i suppose)